# 3-phase energy meter with CTs

Tags: energy, power-meter

I need to measure 3-phases. Usually I would use CTs on the differential port on a LTC1966, then connect Vout+ to an ADC port on a uC.

I do that on a 1-phase application. The problem is now, that we have only one available ADC port in our existing application and it cannot be changed. However, we could use I2C (RX/TX) communication.

As example, I could use three LTC1966 and some uC with more ADC and send data through RX/TX or maybe even a standalone ADC. But if possible I would like a SoC.

We cannot touch existing installed cables therefore the usage of CTs. I also know of the problem not actually being able to measure the real voltage level on each phase, but as said, cannot go into existing installation.

Comment: What is the problem with plugging the meter into a nearby 3-phase socket to measure the voltage? You will absolutely trash any kind of precision without a direct voltage measurement on 3 phase. CTs are fine (can be better than 2%) for current measurement, but because the voltage waveforms are generally very distorted in medium power applications, you need the actual measurement instead of a model waveform.

Comment: The Problem is that I cannot assume that there are any available sockets for me to use. Otherwise that would have been a great idea. I do know about the problem with imbalance, but there is no way for me to make a physical connection.

Comment: For what it's worth, +/- 5% mains voltage variation is normal in most parts of the world. So if you assume nominal voltage, your power meter is going to have an error of +/- 5% even before you consider harmonics and phase imbalance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you can accept the error induced by not measuring the voltage, it may be that you are looking for a reasonable estimation, rather than actual usage.

In 3 phase systems, the power is supposed to be drawn in a balanced manner.  Putting more load on one or another phase than the others results in system inefficiencies.

So a well designed piece of equipment, or plant, will generally be drawing the same power from each phase.  As such you can simply measure one phase, and multiply it by three to obtain an estimated power usage.

If you know your device will be used in situations where the three phase usage is unbalanced, then a simple method would be to use the one ADC, but add an analog switch such as the 4052 CMOS multiplexor to switch the current transformers into the ADC:

[image: CMOS chip 4052, 2 of 4 multiplexor/selector]

You'll need to keep the resistors on the current transformers, and only switch the ADC input to each one, never leave the current transformers "open" which attached to the AC lines.  It'll require 2 I/O from your existing board, but rather than a complex communication protocol and additional code for another microcontroller, it should be pretty simple to control and use.

This will allow you to take sequential readings of the current transformers, so you won't get simultaneous instantaneous data, but you can certainly find average power usage over all three phases several times a second.  With careful timing you can read each one at its positive and negative peak in order, and get nearly as accurate results as if you had three ADCs reading more frequently.

Beyond that, your solution of an offboard "expansion" device that employs another microcontroller to do the job would certainly work well.  I'm not sure it would be much more expensive than the switched chip above either (the cost difference between the MCU and the cmos chip would be swamped by the labor and PCB costs), but it would involve more development time than the simple multiplexed solution.

Comment: how would you measure power when you are switching to a different phase and how do you propose to do this even if you had a reference voltage on one of the phases. My answer stands but thank you for your comment.

Comment: I know the answer and \$\therefore\$ don't need to ask but it seems that your proposal would not make any distinction between reactive and real power consumed.

Comment: ditto dude (btw good answer on the gps stuff way back when)

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to how accurate you want it to be. Can you ignore imbalanced 3-phase loads (the assumption being that all three currents are equal and at the same phase angle to their respective phase voltage)?

> I also know of the problem not actually being able to measure the real
>   voltage level on each phase

This is the big problem - not being able to measure the real voltage level on each phase. If you don't have a waveform of voltage how will you calculate power - you cannot know the phase relationship between voltage and current i.e. is the load resistive or somewhat reactive.

Another problem is current harmonics - if the applied voltage is a sinewave and the load has significant harmonics at 2F, 3F, 4F etc., these harmonics DO NOT contribute to power consumption BUT they are factored into any RMS measurement of current - how will you deal with these (if any) if you can't multiply (in real time) volts and amps with a decent enough sampling frequency?

If you assume that the load has a fixed phase angle i.e. the resistive and reactive components are always in the same ratio, AND you assume this load is balanced, AND you assume the supply voltage does vary (and you know its RMS value), AND you assume the supply is a sinewave, AND you assume the supply is balanced, AND you assume there are no current harmonics then all you need is a CT and one input.

Comment: Well, ofc as you say. There is a lot of problem with this setup and it is also very good of you to point out the problems. But what I needed is the solution. I have to "believe" there are no harmonics or voltage drops. Each phase will theoretically have 230V and then use CTs to RMS circuits for detection of load variation on different phases.

Comment: Then this question comes down to how you get more ADC inputs and the methods you suggest in your question will suffice but all you are achieving is a measurement of currenton each phase and it's unrealistic to believe this can be used to measure energy usage.

Comment: Try scoping the current at the input to a device with a 3 phase rectifier. Until you have seen for your self the distortion even a low power 3 phase devica(less than 10A, on each phase) trashes the the voltage wave form and the current can have 4 spikes per cycle. Measurement in these conditions is difficult without getting all the data. See The Line Current(phase A) Waveform in http://services.eng.uts.edu.au/~venkat/pe_html/ch05s2/ch05s2p1.htm

Comment: While this 'answer' addresses the problem of inaccurate measurement, it doesn't address the problem the OP is asking about, and only expands on comments already existing.  Please consider adding to this answer so it fits the question, or convert it to a comment.